Difference in definition and declaration not detected by gcc?
I'm building a software with arm-none-eabi-gcc 10.2 (-01, -Wall)
I have the following files (obviously not the actual files that i'm not allowed to publish):
header1.h
// variable definition
bool b_myBool;

Type bool is redeclared in my software to unsigned char
header2.h
// variable declaration, const is to be sure the variable is not modified in this translation unit
extern const bool b_myBool;

file2.c
#include <header2.h>


void myFunction(void)
{
    bool l_localBool;
    ...
    if (l_localBool != b_myBool)
    {
       do something;
    }
}

Now I accidently modified header2.h to:
extern const float b_myBool;

And I didn't get any warning (despite the -Wall compilation option), neither because declaration and definition type do not match, nor because the comparison operands have different types (I know comparing a float and an int is defined by the standard since the int will be converted to a float, it's just strange there is not a warning for this).

Do you know about the concept of translation units? The compiler itself only deals with translation units, which in short is a single source with all its included header file. If you have one global symbol declared differently in different translation units then you will have undefined behavior. Unfortunately it's nothing the compiler or linker can detect.

Indeed there is no compile time conflict. So the absence of warning on definition/declaration mismatch makes sense.

Why do you have a definition in a header file?!

@n.m.couldbeanAI it's uncommon but not forbidden. The goal is to control what .c file uses what variable. Used in safety critical systems

The most common model used for implementing C is that each translation unit1 is compiled separately and little or no information about the types of symbols is included in the object modules produced by compilation. When the linker links different object modules together, it cannot do type-checking because the type information is not in the object modules.
You show a declaration of b_myBool in header1.h2, but you do not show header1.h included in any other file, particularly not in file2.c. Since header1.h is not included in file2.c, but header2.h is, the compiler does not see the declaration in header1.h while it is compiling file2.c, and therefore it cannot check the declaration in header1.h with the declaration in header2.h.
If you must have an externally linked object, the practice used by most C programmers is:

Put a definition of the object in one source file, say foo.c.
Put a declaration of the object that is not a definition in one header file, say foo.h.
Use a #include directive to include foo.h in foo.c and in each source file that uses the object.
Compile each source file and link the resulting object files together.

The fact that foo.h is included in foo.c means the compiler will see both the definition in the source file and the declaration in the header during the same compilation, so it can and will check the type. Then the fact that foo.h is included in each other source file that needs the object means it will get the same declaration that is checked when foo.c is compiled.
Footnotes
1 A translation unit is the entire source code being compiled that results from one source code file with all of its #include statements replaced by the included header files.
2 Every definition is a declaration. bool b_myBool; is a tentative definition. A tentative definition is not actually a definition but may cause a definition to be created.


And I didn't get any warning (despite the -Wall compilation option), neither because declaration and definition type do not match, nor because the comparison operands have different types (I know comparing a float and an int is defined by the standard since the int will be converted to a float, it's just strange there is not a warning for this).

No, you didn't, the problem is that you are using two different definitions (in two separate header files) in your code and you have changed the type of the variable only in one compilation unit (in the compilation unit that is defined in the wrong header file).
Header files have been introduced to cope with this, but there's no way for the compiler that is compiling the extern declaration to know that there's another compilation unit in which the variable has been defined otherwise.
header files make the extern declaration to be shared between the client code and the server code (the server of the variable itself) to have a common declaration that is shared. Your problem is that you use two different header files with different declarations of the variable.  The compiler doesn't know about anything that has been compiled separately, so you will not get even a warning, because what you have done is to inform the compiler that the variable is defined differently in this compilation (but defined elsewhere, not here)
The compiler needs to know what is the type of the variable in both files... but you have used different declarations, as they reside in different header files, which are not included crossing compilation units.
Even if you compile both compilation units in the same command line, the two compilations are independent as to make this different declaration invisible from one compilation to the other.  If you want to have a function declared in some compilation unit and only accessible in readonly mode from the rest of the universe, declare an accessor function that gives you a copy of the value (well you can read it and change the read value, but you cannot change the source) and declare the variable static in the implementation module where that variable is actually defined.
